# Unable to build AWS C++ SDK for Amazon Trino connector

Tags: sdk, odbc, driver, trino

I could not build the Amazon Trino ODBC driver though I followed the [developer guideline](https://github.com/skilld-labs/trino-odbc/blob/main/docs/markdown/setup/developer-guide.md).

To be more specific, here below is the required remote repository:
git clone --recurse-submodules -b "1.11.80" "https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-cpp.git".

However, there are no "trino-query" or "trino-write" thus, I couldn't build it.

The arguments I passed: [click here to check the script](https://github.com/skilld-labs/trino-odbc/blob/main/scripts/build_aws-sdk-cpp.ps1)

```
cmake $SRC_DIR -A $WIN_ARCH
-D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$INSTALL_DIR -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=$CONFIGURATION
-D BUILD_ONLY="core;sts;trino-query;trino-write" -D ENABLE_UNITY_BUILD="ON"
-D CUSTOM_MEMORY_MANAGEMENT="OFF" -D ENABLE_RTTI="OFF"
-D ENABLE_TESTING="OFF" `
-D CPP_STANDARD="17"
```

Output:

-- Add s3-crt:s3 to C2J_SPECIAL_NAME_LIST
-- Considering core
-- Considering sts
-- Considering trino-query
-- Considering trino-write
CMake Error at cmake/sdks.cmake:165 (message):
trino-query is required for build, but
generated/src/aws-cpp-sdk-trino-query directory is missing!
Call Stack (most recent call first):
CMakeLists.txt:245 (include)

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

the same error for trino-write too.

I was wondering if anyone could help.